# How to retrieve value from the highest/last level node using 'ChildEventListener' from Firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key-value

I have several strings stored under specific reference: `mReference.child(rID).child(userID2)` which I want to retrieve using `childEventListener` as I am doing some task also when these string gets removed and that is only possible with `onChildRemoved` of `ChildEventListener`.

Here's what I  have tried:

```
mReference.child(rID).child(userID2).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d("dataHEre", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
}
```

The problem is that I'm unable to retrieve data using `keys` here as `dataHEre` is logging out:

```
D/dataHEre: 28.8419556
D/dataHEre: 78.779063
D/dataHEre: 3
D/dataHEre: Railway Colony
D/dataHEre: Sleep
D/dataHEre: 12:36 AM
D/dataHEre: Superman
```

which are `values`?

So, **I want to know how** can I retrieve data here using `keys` and using `ChildEventListener` and then assign the data retrieved to various strings?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing your query in the wrong way. `onChildAdded` method is retrieving you each child of a specific value (userID2 I suppose). If that is what you want, then just use a `onValueEventListener()` to retrieve the whole dataSnapshot of your userId2 node each time that it changes.

If you want to retrieve the data just once, you should use `onSingleValueEventListener()`. And `OnChildEvent()` is used to retrieve lists of data where you want to track each of the child individually. For example if you attach an `OnChildEventListener` to `mReference.child(rID)` you will get a `OnChildAdded` for each userId, what is pretty usefull like for example fill a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView` being able to update each item individually together with your Firebase Data.

If i'm not wrong what you want is just get updates of your `userId2` reference, in that case attach a `OnValueEventListener` to that reference and you will get a call each time a value is modified, deleted, or added.

```
 firebaseDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        customPOJO customPOJO = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourCustomPOJO.class);
        customPOJO.getName();
        customPOJO.getEmail();
        customPOJO.getfavoriteFood();
        //and so on....

     }

     @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
  });
```

Comment: I got your point.. and I already have tried it but as I've mentioned in the question `I want to retrieve using childEventListener as I am doing some task also when these string gets removed and that is only possible with onChildRemoved`. This is the problem :/

Comment: What I mean, is that if you use `ValueEventListener` when you delete and String you will recieve a `onDataChange` data with your new item, and then you can do `myNewItem.getMyDesiredString()` and if you removed your `String`, that call will return you null, then you can do the task that you want.