# Update and delete data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database:

```
{
  "UID1" : {
    "KEY" : {
      "Name" : "name1",
      "Email" : "something1@something.com",
      "userid" : "UID1"
    }
  },
  "UID2" : {
    "KEY2" : {
      "Name" : "name1",
      "Email" : "something1@something.com",
      "userid" : "UID2"
    },
    "KEY3" : {
      "Name" : "name2",
      "Email" : "something2@something.com",
      "userid" : "UID2"
    },
    "KEY4" : {
      "Name" : "name3",
      "Email" : "something3@something.com",
      "userid" : "UID2"
  }
}
```

I would like to update and delete data which for example would be at the position of "KEY2".

How can I achieve this? I have not yet tried any code in Android.

Comment: Please consider adding the structure of your database in a JSON format and also everything you have already tried. If you have not tried doing this yet, please read the Firebase documentation as it explains all of this and can answer your questions.

Comment: @hotrod please see update

Comment: @hotrod that sounds correct

Comment: Perfect, now your question is actually understandable. There is already an answer now which looks correct!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To write single data you can use the `setValue()` method on your `DatabaseReference` with your child Id's:

```
private void writeNewData(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);    
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

In your case you can do something like:
`mDatabase.child("UID2").child("KEY2").setValue(yourNewValueOrObject);`

If you want to update a specific value, you should be more concise:
`mDatabase.child("UID2").child("KEY2").child("email").setValue(newEmail);`

Anyway I recomend you to use custom classes as POJO's(Plain Old Java Object) with the values of each of your items in database. For example:

```
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Finally to remove data you should use the `removeValue()` method in the same way.

```
  private void deleteUserData(String userId) {           
        mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).removeValue();
    }
```

This method will remove the whole reference from your Database, so be care  with it. In the case that you wanted to remove a specific field, you should add another `.child()` call to the tree. For example, let's say that we want to remove the email value from "KEY2" node:
`mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("email").removeValue();`

Finally, there's the case that maybe we want to update multiple fields in different database nodes. In that case we should use the `updateChildren()` method with a map of references and values.

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {
   // Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
   // /posts/$postid simultaneously
   String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
   Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
   Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

   Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
   childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
   childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

   mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

What `updateChildren` method do. Is a `setValue ()` call over each row in the given `Map<String, Object>` being the key the full reference of the node and the Object the value.

You can read more update and delete data in the official [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: Regarding the removal. I want to say for  example remove all data from KEY2 how can I do that?

Comment: Remove the whole Reference from "KEY2":
`mDatabase.child("UID2").child("KEY2").removeValue();`

Comment: `removeValue()` remove the whole reference. You don' need to add "KEY2" as a parammeter, anyway, you can't. 
In the case that you want to remove a single value INSIDE "KEY2"
You should do: `mDatabase.child("UID2").child("KEY2").child(email).removeValue();`

Comment: Great thanks. I will give both of the solution a try and keep you updated

Comment: I added more information to the post, like how to update data from multiple nodes at once. Anyway I recommend you to pause and read the documentation of firebase to learn how to work with it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Don't forget to flag the answers and comments to make easier the search for more people with the same questions than you ;)

Comment: Will do. Just trying out the solutions. Thanks for the detailed answer btw.

Comment: This might sound silly because the code you provided to update data looks correct however, the data is not being updated in Firebase. I have checked using Log.d and the uID and pushId matches to that of data in database.

Comment: I am writing data as you have suggested, passing values as parameters in the constructor.

Comment: Update your code above, anyway, check first that your FirebaseRules doesn't requiere any condition like a logged user or something like that:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/?hl=en

Comment: Sorry silly me, I was passing the same value instead of the new ones and thats why it didn't update them. Works fine now. will try the remove from database. Thanks again

Comment: Great! both work. Accepted but I need 15 rep to vote up :( Can I ask currently when item get deleted from the database it does not automatically disappear from my application. I think the reclyerview does not get updated. Do you know how it can be fixed?

Comment: You should use a `onChildEvent` in your `RecyclerView`, that Listener will update each one of your childrens individually. Instead of make a full query again and reload the full `adapter`, which is pretty bad in performance and user experience.

Comment: I am not sure where I should write that. My code looks like this: http://paste.ofcode.org/ZqTKxgghBXe6xWzx6gafdC

Comment: You should ask that in other question. Anyway debug your code in the `fetchData` method, there's your problem I think.

Comment: I have asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872655/data-from-firebase-does-not-automatically-get-updated-on-reclyerview-android please can you see if you can find a solution

Comment: @FranciscoDurdinGarcia have a look at this too please: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41842681/6144372

Answer (score -3):

This is the complete code to insert , delete, updatte and select from firebase database manually. addvalueListner() is justt used to get all values from database at begining in oncreate().

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText e1,e2,e3;
    Button b1,b2;
    int i;
   static int p=0;
    String key,s1,s2,s3;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    DataSnapshot dsp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e1=findViewById(R.id.editText);
        e2=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3=findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        b1=findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("mydata");


        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dsp=dataSnapshot;

          }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
   }

    public void selectdata(View view) {
                   s3=e3.getText().toString();
                    String s=dsp.child(s3).getValue().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }

    public void removedata(View view) {

        s3=e3.getText().toString();
        databaseReference.child(s3).removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "remove data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void insertperticul(View view) {

        p=0;

      s1=e1.getText().toString();
      s2=e2.getText().toString();
      s3=e3.getText().toString();

       for(DataSnapshot childdata: dsp.getChildren())
       {
           key=childdata.getKey().toString();
            if(s3.equals(key))
            {
                p=1;
                Toast.makeText(this, "User exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

       }
       if(p==0)
       {
           User user=new User(s1,s2);
           databaseReference.child(""+s3).setValue(user);
       }
    }

    public void updatedata(View view) {

        s1=e1.getText().toString();
        s2=e2.getText().toString();
        s3=e3.getText().toString();
        for(DataSnapshot childdata: dsp.getChildren())
        {
            key=childdata.getKey().toString();
            if(s3.equals(key))
            {

                User user=new User(s1,s2);
                databaseReference.child(""+s3).setValue(user);

                Toast.makeText(this, "data updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}



public class User {
    String name;
    String email;

    public User()
    {

    }
    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enetr name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enter email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="selectdata"
        android:text="Select"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:onClick="removedata"
        android:text="Remove"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:onClick="insertperticul"
        android:text="Insert"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enetr Id"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:onClick="updatedata"
        android:text="Update"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```