# After authenticating user, retrieve username from firebase database and display it on navigation drawer header

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After authenticating user, retrieve username from firebase database and display it on navigation drawer header .This is my draweractivity and here i have tried datasnapshot too but it returns me null at navigation header!
it says welcome null.

isnt there any method like user.getNamefromDatabase();

```
package com.example.dell.Swing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private TextView textView;
private Button Logout;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private Profile profile;
private ImageView profilePictureImageView;
private TextView userNameTextView;
// private TextView welcomeText;
// private Button logout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

    if( firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null && profile == null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity2.class));
        finish();
        return;
    }


    if(profile == null){
        FirebaseUser user= firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userNameTextView = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_user_name);
        userNameTextView.setText("Welcome"+user.getEmail());
    }else{
        profilePictureImageView = (ImageView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        userNameTextView =(TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_user_name);

        Picasso.with(this).load(profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200)).into(profilePictureImageView);
        userNameTextView.setText(profile.getName());
    }




}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}





@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity2.class));
        MainActivity.this.finish();


    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way you have to retrieve your user name is from your `FirebaseUser` instance. So you will need retrieve a correct value from `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` to be able to call `getDisplayName()` to retrieve the user's name, `getEmail()` to retrieve the user's email and `getPhotoUrl()`to retrieve the user's photo url.

Other way to achieve that is store the values from your user in FirebaseDatabase. Such like:

```
"userdata" {
     "accountCreationDAate": "2017-01-25 22:57",
     "age" : 25,
     "username" : "myName",
     "photoUrl" : "customUrl"
......
```

In that way you will be able to retrieve the user's data also from your database. However, is more simple to retrieve that important values as `username`, `photoUrl` and `email` always from the `FirebaseUser` instance.

Comment: can you please demonstrate! i already stored my user details into firebase ,i just dont know how to retrieve them.

Comment: I suggest you to read about it in the official Firebase documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write
Also you can check how to correctly store data using Firebase in other community questions such as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869606/update-and-delete-data-in-firebase