# Firebase node update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update a single field of the node i.e notify to 0/1 having 'schedule_id=1'.I have tried a lot of procedures but not able to update or sometimes.

I also have tried this solution but failed ([Update and delete data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869606/update-and-delete-data-in-firebase)) this is adding a new node

Firebase structure:

```
 {
   "schedule":{
      "21-11-2017":{
         "route":{
            "1":{
               "kid":{
                  "21":{
                     "-KzDdfZtds7rxwETF4oN":{
                        "color":"#B71C1C",
                        "delay_time":"45 mins delay",
                        "is_active":"0",
                        "msg":"Driver out of garage",
                        "notify":"dsds",
                        "real_time":"10:30 PM",
                        "schedule_id":"1",
                        "schedule_time":"5:00"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried this code.
In this case, problem is happening like the debugger is not getting inside 'query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

```
private void updatefirebsenode() {
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        Query query = reference.child("schedule").child("21-11-2017").child("route").child("1").child("kid").child("21").orderByChild("schedule_id").equalTo("1");
///from this line debugger is exiting 
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot nodeDataSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
                String key = nodeDataSnapshot.getKey(); // this key is `K1NRz9l5PU_0CFDtgXz`
                String path = "/" + dataSnapshot.getKey() + "/" + key;
                HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                result.put("notify", "1");
                reference.child(path).updateChildren(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              //  Logger.error(TAG, ">>> Error:" + "find onCancelled:" + databaseError);
            }
        });
    }
```

Schedule POJO class

```
public class Schedule {
    private String delay_time;
    private String is_active;
    private String real_time;
    private String schedule_id;
    private String schedule_time;
    private String color;
    private String noti_message;
    private String notify;
    private transient Context context;


    public Schedule(String notify) {
        this.notify = notify;
    }

    public Schedule() {
    }

    public String getDelay_time() {
        return delay_time;
    }

    public void setDelay_time(String delay_time) {
        this.delay_time = delay_time;
    }

    public String getIs_active() {
        return is_active;
    }

    public void setIs_active(String is_active) {
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }

    public String getReal_time() {
        return real_time;
    }

    public void setReal_time(String real_time) {
        this.real_time = real_time;
    }

    public String getSchedule_id() {
        return schedule_id;
    }

    public void setSchedule_id(String schedule_id) {
        this.schedule_id = schedule_id;
    }

    public String getSchedule_time() {
        return schedule_time;
    }

    public void setSchedule_time(String schedule_time) {
        this.schedule_time = schedule_time;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getNoti_message() {
        return noti_message;
    }

    public void setNoti_message(String noti_message) {
        this.noti_message = noti_message;
    }

    public String getNotify() {
        return notify;
    }

    public void setNotify(String notify) {
        this.notify = notify;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using updateChildren you can use setValue method to set the value of schedule_id but first of all you must have reference to schedule_id node.

```
   final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("schedule").child("21-11-2017").child("route").child("1").child("kid").child("21").orderByChild("schedule_id");
                        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String schedule_id =(String )dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                                                    mDatabase.setValue("setDesiredValueTo Schedule_id");
                                Log.wtf("MYLOG", "onDataChange: schedule_id updated" );
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
```

my Example to update user points:

```
final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(created_by_referalUsername).child("pointsTotal");
                        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String points =(String )dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                int i  =Integer.valueOf(points);
                                i +=250;
                                mDatabase.setValue(i);
                                Log.wtf("MYLOG", "onDataChange: points added to referal owner profile" );
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
```

this may help you.

Comment: im not sure either my reference is correct or not but the method is 100% correct

Comment: Can be more specific.my requirement is to update the 'notify' node to 0 when the schedule id equals to '1'

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `getChildren()` method it means that you are iterating  on the `dataSnapshot` object which in term means that you are getting all the keys and not only one. To be able to use a particular key that is generated by the `push()` method, you need to store it first into a field using this line of code:

```
String key = yourRef.push().getKey();
```

So when you are pushing for a new key, is the moment in which you can store it.

In order to update a value of a field in a Firebase database, you don't need to attach a listener, you can only use `setValue()` method directly on the reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("schedule")
    .child("21-11-2017")
    .child("route")
    .child("kid")
    .child("21")
    .child("-KzDdfZtds7rxwETF4oN")
    .child("notify")
    .setValue("1");
```

Comment: the firebase node is created from the server / php end.My job is to update the notify node when my job is done in the android end

Comment: In this case, the php server should send you the key for which you must do the update. You cannot use a key in your `DatabaseReference` without knowing it and you cannot simply query your database for a key that you literally don't know it.