# How to copy ratingbar value to firebase database android?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a simple app for my school that the user will rate the service and press submit, which sends the data to firebase, but at the same time, resets the value of the rating bar so the next user can rate again. But I am having some difficulties and misunderstandings. Please Help! Here is my main activity code:

```
    package com.timothy.ratingch;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.hsalf.smilerating.SmileRating;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SmileRating mRatingBar;
    private DatabaseReference mRatingBarCh;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SmileRating smileRating = (SmileRating) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference mRatingBarCh = rootRef.child("ratings");


        smileRating.setOnRatingSelectedListener(new SmileRating.OnRatingSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingSelected(int level, boolean reselected) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your feedback value is " + level,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mRatingBarCh.child("rating").setValue(String.valueOf(level));

                // reselected is false when user selects different smiley that previously selected one
                // true when the same smiley is selected.
                // Except if it first time, then the value will be false.
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.timothy.ratingch.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
        android:text="Please Rate Our Service at CH!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.hsalf.smilerating.SmileRating
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:background="#dfeded"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text="SEND FEEDBACK"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        float rating = ratingBar.getRating();
        mRatingBarCh.child("rating").setValue(String.valueOf(rating));
    }
});
```

The problem in your code is that you are passing a `view` to the `setValue()` method and not a supported data type.

And also don't forget to intialize your `mRatingBarCh` field like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mRatingBarCh = rootRef.child("ratings");
```

Comment: please help @AlexMamo

Comment: please help me @AlexMamo

Comment: I will. What is the problem?

Comment: it did succeed to send data but it only overrites the old data @AlexMamo

Comment: when i looked at the data in firebase it just overrwrites the old data @AlexMamo

Comment: Then use `updateChildren()` method instead of `setValue()`.

Comment: get error @AlexMamo that cannot use String with java.lang.object only can use string

Comment: That's correct. You need to `updateChildren()` with a Map, not with a String. Take a look [here](updateChildren()) and [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869606/update-and-delete-data-in-firebase). And keep me posted.

Comment: sorry, I don't really get how to use the Map, i'm still new with android studio so can you please help me? @AlexMamo

Comment: Map<String, Object> postValues = post.map
                Map<String, Object> ratingUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                ratingUpdates.put("rating" + level);


                mRatingBarCh.child("rating").updateChildren();

Comment: could you help me @AlexMamo

Comment: In order to make this work, I insist to read the basics of Java. Maps, Java objects and so on for a better understanding.

Comment: hi @AlexMamo , i just used the traditional method to add firebase data and it worked: String rating = Integer.toString(level);

                mRatingBarCh.push().setValue(rating);

Comment: There is one more thing that you can do. Post another fresh question including all the details, so me or other users can help you.

Comment: Will do in the future!! @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You are setting value inside rating change listener which will gets triggered as soon as you change the rating.
Add a listener on your send feedback button and then on click set the value in firebase:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get the value of rating from rating bar
        mRatingBarCh.child("rating").setValue(v);
        // reset your rating bar
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont really get it sir, would you mind explaining more?

Comment: you said that you want to send the feedback only when button is clicked so you should set the value in database on the click of button, not on the change of rating bar.

Comment: could you teach me how? I really am a beginner to firdatabase sir @UmarHussain

Comment: please help @Umar